# Connecting mySQL table to itself to cross check results?

Tags: mysql

Not sure that's the best question title, but what I have is this:

db: usernames

```
id, username, search_via, value_1
1, Rita, Sue, 1
2, Bob, Sue, 2
3, Bill, Sue, 3
4, Jim, Bill, 4
5, Brian, Bob, 5
```

I want to be able to search for the all the users with a search_via of 'Sue', so obviously I have:

```
SELECT * FROM usernames WHERE search_via = 'Sue':
1, Rita, Sue, 1
2, Bob, Sue, 2
3, Bill, Sue, 3
```

...but then I want, from those results, to also return any usernames which appear as a search_via as well, so in the case it would be 'Brian', as it is a search_via value for Bob, who appeared as a username for 'Sue':

```
5, Brian, Bob, 5
```

..so my full results should be:

```
1, Rita, Sue, 1
2, Bob, Sue, 2
3, Bill, Sue, 3
5, Brian, Bob, 5
```

...because my first search_via name was Sue, and in Sue's results, there was Bob, who was a search_via value for 'Brian'

...I've really struggled explaining this, so I have absolutely zero idea how to go about it?!?

Any ideas?

Comment: Do  you want this search result to extend to third level and beyond as well ?

Comment: Why does n't `4, Jim, Bill, 4` also appear in output ? `Bill` is also searchable *via* `Sue`

Comment: Yes, very much so.

Comment: "Yes, very much so" - Is this answer to my first question ? or the second question ?

Comment: You're right, 'Bill' should also appear. My mistake.

Comment: Does the posted answer work ? Please give feedback. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To get results upto second level hierarchy only, we can simply use a subquery to fetch all the `username` values where `search_via = 'Sue'`. We can then use `WHERE search_via IN (..)` to get second level hierarchy results as well.

```
SELECT * 
FROM usernames 
WHERE search_via = 'Sue' OR 
      search_via IN (
                     SELECT username 
                     FROM usernames 
                     WHERE search_via = 'Sue'
                    )
```

Comment: You are picking up an extra record ([see here](https://rextester.com/WQPL61110)).  Not that my answer seems correct either :-(

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for the fiddle. Actually OP's expected output is wrong. His sample data covers all the usernames actually. Remaining two users are at second level.